# Migrated custom attributes fail

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, migration

With our migrated M2 shops the custom attributed were migrated.
But now the problem is that we must make a choice between 2 options.

The attribute is in mysql a **varchar** but then we can't change the value through the shop. When i change it to **text** we can change it but then it's not used in the filter option on the category page in the shop.

Is there someone who has fixed this problem, because now the option is to make new attributes and fill them all over, but we have 15k+ product so that's not really what we want.

Thanks very much..